# BAD_ACCESS & NSInvalidArgumentException in working with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, datasource, uipickerview

I'm beginner in working with UIKit. When I tired to work with UIPickerView in iOS 7 SDK I faced to a hard-to-solve problem.

We know that UIPickerView needs two resources to work perfectly: dataSource & delegate. So I wrote a class named "KMPickerProtocols". I adopted it to UIPickerViewDataSource & UIPickerViewDelegate Protocols and then I added some extra setter methods to it.

KMPickerProtocols is adopted to all of essential methods of dataSource and delegate Protocols + the necessary optional method for setting title of each row (pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent). all these methods get things done without any problem (in normal situations).

Finally I set the delegate and dataSource properties of my UIPickerView (named _accountPicker) manually with this piece of code:

```
 NSArray *delegateAgent = [[KMTwitterDelegate new] run ];
_accountPicker.dataSource = [delegateAgent objectAtIndex:0];
_accountPicker.delegate = [delegateAgent objectAtIndex:1] ;
```

(the run method is designed to set some properties including height of each row and ...)

Now, when I run my app it will show my twitterAccounts stored in system(accounts framework) in the form of UIPickerView. but there is a problem: As soon as I scroll the picker view or tap on any row, the program will crash and I get BAD_ACCESS (code=2 , address = 0x1) in this line of code:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([KMAppDelegate class]));
}
```

and also there are sometimes that I get signal SIGABRT in above line. in these situations Log Says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[**NSMallocBlock** pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c75ad0'

I will appreciate if you help me to deal with this problem. I really don't know where the bug is. but I guess this screen shots will be helpful to find that:

[image: First implementation of method]
 [image: Second implementation]
[image: Third implementation]

The problem in above screenshot is that UIPicker called the "pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent" method for row 0, three times instead of one time. I just don't know whether that is this because myFault or because the typical behaviour of UIPicker.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the message `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` to an object of type `NSMallocBlock`. This is a message automatically sent from the picker to its datasource, so my assumption is that you are assigning the datasource:

```
_accountPicker.dataSource = [delegateAgent objectAtIndex:0];
```

The datasource you assign does not conform the protocol `UIPickerViewDataSource`

Checkout what returns `[delegateAgent objectAtIndex:0];` and make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you. I had checked it, it was exactly what I expected. and in the first run of app, there is no problem, but when you play with picker these bad things happen.